# Appdomain recycle settings on mod_mono & Apache

Tags: asp.net, apache, mono, mod-mono

How does one control the application recycle settings for an ASP.NET application runnin on mod_mono & Apache ?

On IIS6 & 7 there was an option to specify either a time period, a number of requests, etc. when the AppDomain would be recycled and the application would basically do an Application_End() / Application_Start().

I am seeing the same behaviour on mod_mono & Apache ,but I can't find where to change the settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is, from http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono#Automatic_restart_of_the_mod-mono-server_backend

SO formatting is a little off, but basically you can restart *mod-mono-server* process ( running under apache ) by time or requests using this configuration.

> **Automatic restart of the
>   mod-mono-server backend**
>
> mod_mono can automatically restart the
>   Mono (mod-mono-server) backend that is
>   handling requests after a certain
>   amount of time. This is useful if you
>   find that the mono process is growing
>   indefinitely over time, or if you just
>   need to make sure you clean house
>   every so often.
>
> There are two automatic restart
>   methods: one based on time, and one
>   based on the number of requests
>   served. You can active them as
>   follows:
>
> Auto-restart after three hours. 
>   1 MonoAutoRestartMode Time 
>   2 MonoAutoRestartTime 00:03
>
> The time format above is
>   DD[:HH[:MM[:SS]]].
>
> Auto-restart after 10,000 requests served. 
>   1 MonoAutoRestartMode Requests
>   2 MonoAutoRestartRequests 10000
>
> As with most other mod_mono
>   directives, the first parameter to a
>   directive can be the name or alias of
>   a mod-mono-server. This is always
>   optional and is omitted in the
>   examples above.

Comment: Kervin, I have a related question involving mod_mono app recycles that I would greatly appreciate your input on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480328

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this [link](http://www.mono-project.com/CGI) that explains the Fast CGI module, I would guess there would need to be a script that is run periodically by the cron job to kill the process and restart it... I do not know if this would be of any help to you. You did not state what OS, I am making an assumption that this is on a Win Platform? If you are on a Windows platform, then it would be easy enough to schedule a script to restart the Mod_Mono extension in effect "recycling"...