# C# (mono) Linux web server hosting with consistent static variables across threads

Tags: c#, linux, mono, webserver, hosting

Does anybody know of a C# (mono) Linux web server hosting configuration that enables consistent static variables across threads (ie not the CGI model of an instance per thread)?

**Details**

I have some c# (mono) code that we need to host on linux as part of a simple web app.  We don't need any traditional asp or even asp.net mvc features, really we just need the ability to respond to specific urls with dynamic content based on shared static variables.

**Static Variables:**
The one special requirement we do have is that we need static variables to retain their value across all incoming requests (the same way they do on windows with an ASP.net mvc application).  Common ways of hosting a mono c# web app like Apache mod_mono appear to use an 'c# application instance per thread' model where there would be multiple independent instances of our c# application each with their own static variables.  That is the problem we need to avoid.  I need a way of hosting a c# application that provides one common app with a shared set of static variables that all incoming requests will see.  It is ok if when the app recycles that the static variables get reset (just like in normal IIS/MVC), so long as recycles are infrequent.

The background is that this web app needs to hold a large amount of data in RAM in a static variable and rapidly answer questions about that data. Having a copy of the app open for each thread would limit RAM resources too much and reloading the data into memory frequently would make the app too slow (occasional recycles like IIS/Asp.net MVC has are fine).  The system works amazingly well on Windows/IIS7 (50,000+ dynamic requests per second) and we **do not** want change this architecture, so the answer I'm looking for relates to hosting not changing the application design.

Comment: Maybe mod_mono works with the apache worker mpm (multi-thread)? Default in apache is prefork (multi-process). Even with prefork the same process can serve multiple requests before recycling so you will share statics for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will have my team check this out.  Hopefully, somebody will chime in that has dealt with this issue in production before.  It seems like this might work but it could be  tricky to test the rate of recycling which if too frequent in production would be debilitating.

Comment: Looking in the docs, I don't see anything suggesting that multiple servers would be spawned.  It is strange that it would.  An option to get around this would be to start the Mono server independently and have Apache use that running instance: http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono#Unix_and_TCP_sockets

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Brian. Do you think the TCP approach is as reliable as the Apache approach? These two posts were what made us think that instance spawning might be a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241425 and serverfault.com/a/101895/83292

Comment: Thank you both for the input.  Next week we're going to attempt a production scale test of Apache Mod_mono with a cluster of about a hundred computers.   I'll report back on how the config goes and maybe a IIS vs Mod mono benchmark if we can fit it in. In the mean time if anyone has any config pointers for mod_mono I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Rather than use Apache Mod_mono, have you tried running xsp as a standalone process?

Comment: @Cookie I am interested in XSP and find it appealing that it appears to work on both Windows and Linux allowing for more debug & deployment options. Do you know if XSP has matured to "production grade" I know it was originally a 'google summer of code' project and for a long time there were lots of comments on the web saying that it was reliable enough for debugging only.  I've been thinking about giving this article a shot but its old and likely out of date. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9738/Introduction-to-Mono-ASP-NET-with-XSP-and-Apache  Have a favorite XSP2 article?

Comment: @Glenn We have been using xsp on a production site since 2006. Our main experience is using it under Centos hosting a series of webservices. We have found it to be very stable, servicing many thousands of requests a day without issue. It does have a few undocumented "features" for example when we started using it nullable types were not handled correctly when generating a wsdl.

Comment: @Cookie Thanks for the great practical usage stat. I'm thinking XSP is the right fit for us.  Have you had any trouble with memory leaks or crashing under load?  I'm trying to decide if we need to write a boot strap to monitor and restart XSP in those kinds of cases or if there is some other preferred process for handling those cases.

Comment: Hi Glenn, you've asked for my input, although I'm not sure whether it is still needed :) Sincerely, I do not have much experience with the mod_mono. Apart from the mentioned option of simply using XSP (as one can see, the user experience is rather positive, though I'm not sure you can reach the performance you need), you can also check how the FastCGI mono server behaves.

Comment: @konrad.kruczynski  Thanks for looking.  In the past we have found this initial setup and config stage to the the highest risk for big losses of wasted time so I'm trying to understand the potential issues are before we dive in.  If we don't hit 50,000 requests per second on a single XSP instance that's ok as long as its reasonably fast (maybe 10,000 per sec?) we can scale horizontally.. nice to not have to buy 100 windows server licenses or pay the windows premium on amazon.. although if IIS is 40/50% faster then it starts to become a tossup cost wise.  I'll report back with some stats.

Comment: Read my answer, there is no reason why mod_mono should spawn multiple mono processes, so using xsp shouldn't be needed. However, if you really look into scaling your .NET app, I can tell you using Nginx together with mono via fastcgi performs really well, as nginx with its good caching / reverse proxy capabilities can help you scale your mono-powered app really easy compared to apache.

Comment: Glad to hear mod_mono works well for you.  O

Comment: Your comments about Application Domain seemed like they might not apply to our situation.  I added a followup question below to see if your answer was relevant to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_mono does not spawn a new mono process for each new web request. Neither does it if you use the fastcgi server along with apache or nginx.

EDIT: Static variables are shared within the same Application Domain. This holds true for Microsoft .NET IIS and for mono (no matter if you are using mod_mono, xsp or mono-fastcgi-server). Even so apache spawns multiple worker threads and a single request is handled by a single worker thread, there is only a single mono process running at any given time (except if you have configured multiple asp.net applications, then there is one per application).

Mono tries to achieve 100% compatibility for ASP.NET as well, so there is no different behaviour by design!

The different behaviour of your program on linux is most likely not related to how mod_mono handles requests, but rather a bug in mono itself, or your code (i.e. by making a platform assumption that does not hold true on linux). You should really debug using MonoDevelop/xsp and try to pinpoint the problem more clearly, or paste some sample code here.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, but we appear to not be understanding each other.  I didn't ask about communication across ApplicationDomain boundaries and I know that within a single App Domain static variables work just fine.  Also, as to your suggestion on Application State, Microsoft itself [link to MS HighPerformance blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2010/11/09/high-performance-asp-net-application-1-optimizing-state-management.aspx ] recommends static variables over Application State for high performance applications like ours and I stated I didn't want architecture advice.

Comment: Are you perhaps suggesting that mod_mon divides each thread of a single application into its own ApplicationDomain?  (this would be quite different from the default IIS behavior and perhaps explain your comment about static variables).

Comment: All I am saying is, that mod_mono (should) behave the same way like IIS. Everything else is a bug. If your application does not work with mod_mono, it most likely will not work with xsp or nginx/fastcgi either. Thats why it is not wise to give a hosting advise, as it will not fix your problem.

Comment: thanks for the advice.  we're not encountering any unexpected behavior at the moment and just wanted to confirm that we can expect the different hosting flavors of mod_mono to exhibit the same behavior as IIS with respect to static variables.  There are a few old or incorrect reports on the web that suggest mod_mono behaves differently. Your answer and the comments of others seem to confirm the good news mod_mono should be stable, and consistent with the windows implementation.  thanks for your input

Comment: I appreciate your answer edits and because it seems to now cover the topic accurately I'm going to mark it as the answer.